# Cannot store nested parts of JSON request using robospice and ormlite

Tags: android, json, ormlite, resttemplate, robospice

Hi we using RoboSpice with ORMLite and SpringAndroidSpiceRequest to read
JSON info from webpage and write to SQLite database.

We are using the newest JSON mapper MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.

```
        // Web services support JSON responses
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        FormHttpMessageConverter formHttpMessageConverter = new FormHttpMessageConverter();
        StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> listHttpMessageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
```

We have tried to read nested JSON queries like the below example, we can read
and store to database, the first level of JSON (page, total), but we can't store
the next levet of the JSON array, All the "schedule_date" entries.

We have looked at this example (and many more) as the best example to store the JSON
data. But it doesn't work for us. [RoboSpice persist JSON array with OrmLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835415/robospice-persist-json-array-with-ormlite)

Question: How do we get to read and write the nested JSON keys and values, We
are stumped ! :O

**JSON:**

```
{
   "page": 2,
   "total": 5,
   "result":
   [
       {
           "schedule_date": "2013-08-03"
       },
       {
           "schedule_date": "2013-09-03"
       },
       {
           "schedule_date": "2013-10-03"
       },
       {
           "schedule_date": "2013-11-03"
       },
       {
           "schedule_date": "2013-12-03"
       }
   ]
}
```

**BroadcastResult.java:**

```
            import java.util.Collection;
            import java.util.List;
            import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
            import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;
            import com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField;
            import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

            @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
            @DatabaseTable(tableName="BroadcastResult")
            public class BroadcastResult {

                @DatabaseField(id = true)
                private int page;

                @DatabaseField
                private int total;

                @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
                private Collection<Broadcast> result;

                public int getPage() {
                    return page;
                }

                public void setPage(int page) {
                    this.page = page;
                }

                public int getTotal() {
                    return total;
                }

                public void setTotal(int total) {
                    this.total = total;
                }

                public Collection<Broadcast> getResult() {
                    return result;
                }

                public void setResult(Collection<Broadcast> result) {
                    this.result = result;
                }
            }
```

**Broadcast.java:**

```
            import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
            import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;
            import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

            @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
            @DatabaseTable(tableName="Broadcast")
            public class Broadcast {

                @DatabaseField(id = true)
                private String schedule_date;

                @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
                private BroadcastResult result;

                public String getScheduleDate() {
                    return schedule_date;
                }

                public void setScheduleDate(String schedule_date) {
                    this.schedule_date = schedule_date;
                }

                public void setBroadcastResult(BroadcastResult result) {
                    this.result = result;
                }

                public BroadcastResult getBroadcastResult() {
                    return result;
                }   
            }
```

We got this error, that we do not understand. 
Logcat: SQLiteLog(10637): (1) no such column: result_id

```
@DatabaseField(foreign = true) // also tried (foreign = true, ColumnName="result")
private BroadcastResult result;
```

The complete log for the run test can be seen here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7760344

Comment: Jackson is tricky, I believe that the field names are built not from the private variable names, but from the setters and getters.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private int _id;
```

to your Broadcast.java class?